# how to use multiple row terminator while use bulk insertion from text file to table in sql 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Declare  @SQL_BULK Nvarchar(Max)    

SET @SQL_BULK = 'BULK INSERT TempTable FROM ''' + @FilePath + ''' WITH
        (
        ROWTERMINATOR= ''\nGO'' 
        )
        '

Exec (@SQL_BULK)
```

Comment: What happens when you use this code?  What were you expecting to happen?  It's not clear what you're asking here

Comment: this query is running successfully but i want to use multiple row terminator like '\nGo' , '\thanks', '\nDear' in a single query.

Comment: Using Bulk Insert isn't the solution for this as you can't have multiple row terminators unless you can change the file before hand to replace all the row terminators to one.